# Can you get the W3SVC identifier from IIS6 after a site is deleted?

Tags: iis-7

Since the site has been deleted, the IIS > Web Sites listing to get the identifier doesn't work (since it's not there)

Is there another way to get the identifier?

I have a multitude of LogFiles in system32, all listed by W3SVC ID, but none contain any identifying information about the website it's logging, so I have to go by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by running this cool VBS script on Stack Overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868108/get-iis-web-site-identifier-programmatically

I had to get help identifying the code source, but it worked, and I'm adding it to my 'Tools to fix IIS shit with' ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

- Recreate the site name exactly - the site identifier is (from memory) a short hash of the name
- Fish the old metabase out of the System32\InetSrv\History folder, where the automatic backups are stored.